# AngularJS - How to overwrite $urlRouterProvider.when

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my `AngularJS` application I've got more than one route.js file controlling all my routes.

As a default I have the route `"/"` be equal `"/main"`, but is there a way to later overwrite this?

Let's say I have a route.js like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.when('/','/main');

    $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: "/main",
            templateUrl: 'main.html',
            controller: 'mainController'
        });
});
```

But later I want to dynamically overwrite this default route, with a new one from route2.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.when('/','/newMain');

    $stateProvider
        .state('newMain', {
            url: "/newMain",
            templateUrl: 'newMain.html',
            controller: 'newMainController'
        });
});
```

Comment: How are you ensuring that route2.js is always loading after route.js ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `.when` setting could be not only provided with a constant, it could be even a function.

So, let's have some setting *(e.g. naive global `var useDifferent = false;`)* and hook decision on it:

```
$urlRouterProvider.when("/other", function(){
    if(useDifferent){
      return  "/newMain";
    }
    return "/Main";
});
```

Later, anyone can just change that setting `useDifferent = true` *(or of cause some more, much more smart and correct handling...)*